# Example 4.5-3 in Kryeszig's Functional Analysis: What is the relation between the matrix of a linear operator and that of its adjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite-dimensional normed spaces, either both real or both complex, and let $T \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ be a linear operator. (Then by Theorem 2.7-8 in Kreyszig $T$ is bounded since its domain is finite-dimensional). Let $X^\prime$ denote the dual space of $X$ (i.e. the normed space of all the bounded linear functionals with domain $X$); since $X$ is finite-dimensional, $X^\prime$ consists of all the linear functionals with domain $X$, again by Theorem 2.7-8 in Kreyszig. And, the same applies to $Y^\prime$.

Then the adjoint operator $T^\times \colon Y^\prime \longrightarrow X^\prime$ of $T$ is also a bounded linear operator that is defined as follows: Let $g \in Y^\prime$. Then $T^\times (g) = f \in X^\prime$, where $f$ is defined by $$f(x) = g\big( T(x) \big) \mbox{ for all } x \in X.$$
This operator $T^\times$ is linear and bounded with $$ \left\lVert T^\times \right\rVert = \lVert T \rVert.$$

Now let $E = \left( e_1, \ldots, e_n \right)$ be an ordered basis for $X$, and let $B = \left( b_1, \ldots, b_m \right)$ be an ordered basis for $Y$. Let $A = \left[ \alpha_{ij} \right]_{m \times n}$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to the ordered bases $E$ and $B$.

Let $E^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ denote the dual ordered bases of $E$ and $B$, respectively. Let $A^\times$ be the matrix of $T^\times$ with respect to the dual bases  $B^\prime$ and $E^\prime$.

What is the relation between the matrices $A$ and $A^\times$?

By definition, the dual basis $E^\prime$ of $X^\prime$ corresponding to the ordered basis $E$ for $X$ is the ordered $n$-tuple $\left( f_1, \ldots, f_n \right)$ of linear functionals  with domain $X$ such that, for each $j = 1, \ldots, n$ and for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$,  we have
$$ 
f_j \left( e_k \right) = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if }  j = k; \\ 0 & \mbox{ if }  j \neq k.\end{cases} 
$$

And, similarly the dual basis $B^\prime$ of $B$ is the ordered $m$-tuple $\left( g_1, \ldots, g_m \right)$ of linear functionals  with domain $Y$ such that, for each $r = 1, \ldots, m$ and for each $s = 1, \ldots, n$,  we have
$$f_r \left( e_s \right) = \begin{cases} 1  & \mbox{ if }  r = s; \\ 0 & \mbox{ if }  r \neq s.\end{cases} $$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308162/how-is-the-matrix-of-a-linear-operator-affected-by-a-change-of-bases) is a Math Stack Exchange of mine which contains the relevant terminology and notation.

Comment: I think it should be the inverse of the transposed, but I'm not 100% sure. That is, $A^{\times} = (A^{-1})^T$

Comment: There is no reason to require a normed space.  Indeed, there is no reason to require field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.  The question still makes sense.

Comment: @Riccardo Orlando No need to inverse : transpose only is the right answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie oh well. Inverting seemed reasonable since you sort of go backwards when pushing to the duals... That is, $T^{\times}$ goes from $Y'$ to $X'$

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando can you please read through my edited post and post a detailed answer using the notation consistent with that used herein?

Comment: @JeanMarie can you please read my edited post and post a detailed answer?

Comment: @GEdgar I have just edited my post to make some improvements. So can you please elaborate your comment in a full-blown answer using the notation and terminology familiar to me?

Comment: Dude, it's been 6 years... If you couldn't figure it out by now, I don't think there's much we can do...

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando The author has a sight problem. Perhaps it's difficult for him to follow foreign notations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Aloizio's answer is correct, but still, I'll try to give a more detailed one.

If $A^{\times} = [\alpha_{pq}']$, is the matrix of $T^{\times}$ with respect to the dual bases $B′$ and $E′$, then the number $\alpha_{pq}'$ (element of the $p$-th row, $q$-th column) is equal to the $p$-th coordinate of $T^{\times}(g_q)$ with respect to the basis $E'$. This number is obtained by applying $T^{\times}(g_q)$ to the $p$-th vector of the basis $E$:

$$T^{\times}(g_q)(e_p) = g_q(T(e_p))$$

And this last number is the $q$-th coordinate of $T(e_p)$ with respect to the basis $B$, which is equal to the element of $A$ placed in the $q$-th row, $p$-th column, that is, $\alpha_{qp}$. It follows that $\alpha_{pq}' = \alpha_{qp}$, and so, $A^{\times}$ is the transpose of $A$.

Comment: thank you very much for such a beautifully clear explanation!

Answer (score 4):

We have that $T^{\times}(b_j^{\times})(e_i)=b_j^{\times}(T(e_i))=b_j^{\times}(\sum\limits_k a_{k,i}b_k )=a_{j,i}.$

Therefore,
$$T^{\times}(b_j^{\times})=\sum_{i} a_{j,i}b_i^{\times}.$$

It follows that the matrix representation of the adjoint is the transpose.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could amend your answer by including some more detail as well as modifying the notation and terminology consistent with that used in my post (or the reference given herein toward the end).