# How is the matrix of a linear operator affected by a change of bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

First, we define the matrix of a linear mapping.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over the same field $F$; let $n = \dim X$ and $m = \dim Y$; let $E = \left( e_1, \ldots, e_n \right)$ be an ordered basis for $X$, and $B = \left( b_1, \ldots, b_m \right)$ be an ordered basis for $Y$; and let $T \colon X \to Y$ be a linear mapping.
>
> For any element $x \in X$, there is a unique $n$-tuple $\left( \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \right)$ of scalars (i.e. elements of the field $F$) such that 
>   $$ x = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j e_j. \tag{1}$$ 
>   The column vector 
>   $$ \left[x \right]_E \colon = \left[ \matrix{\alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n } \right] \tag{1a} $$
>   is the *coordinate vector* of $x$ relative to the ordered basis $E$ of the vector space $X$.
>
> Moreover, as $T(x) \in Y$, so there exists a unique ordered $m$-tuple $\left( \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m \right)$ of scalars such that 
>   $$ T(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i b_i. \tag{2}$$
>   Thus the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to the ordered basis $B$ of the vector space $Y$ is given by $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_B = \left[ \matrix{\beta_1 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_m } \right]. \tag{2a} $$ 
>   As $T$ is linear, so by (1), we obtain 
>   $$ T(x) = T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j e_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j T \left( e_j \right). \tag{3}$$ 
>   But as $T \left( e_1 \right)$, $\ldots$, $T\left( e_n \right)$ are also elements of $Y$, so there exist unique ordered $m$-tuples $$\left( \gamma_{11}, \ldots, \gamma_{m1} \right), \ldots, \left( \gamma_{1n}, \ldots, \gamma_{mn} \right)$$ of scalars such that 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> T\left( e_1 \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \gamma_{i1} b_i, \\
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> T\left( e_n \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \gamma_{in} b_i.
> \end{align} \tag{4} 
> $$
>   Thus the coordinate vectors of $T \left( e_1 \right)$, $\ldots$, $T\left( e_n \right)$ relative to the ordered basis $B$ are given by 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left[ T \left( e_1 \right) \right]_B &= \left[ \matrix{ \gamma_{11} \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_{m1} } \right], \\
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> \left[ T \left( e_n \right) \right]_B &= \left[ \matrix{ \gamma_{1n} \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_{mn} } \right]. 
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Then the matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $E$ of $X$ and the ordered basis $B$ of $Y$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ T \right]_{EB} = \left[ \matrix{ \gamma_{11} & \ldots & \gamma_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \gamma_{m1} & \ldots & \gamma_{mn} } \right].$$
>   Now from (3) and (4), we find that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> T(x) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j T \left( e_j \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \alpha_j \sum_{i=1}^m \gamma_{ij} b_i \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_j \gamma_{ij}  b_i  \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j  b_i \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j  b_i \right) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j b_i \right) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j  b_i \right) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j \right) b_i. 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   That is, 
>   $$ T(x) =  \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{ij} \alpha_j \right) b_i.  \tag{5} $$ 
>   So the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to the basis $B$ of $Y$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_B = \left[ \matrix{ \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{1j} \alpha_j \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{mj} \alpha_j } \right]. \tag{5a} $$
>   Since the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to the basis $B$ of $Y$ is unique, therefore from (2a) and (5a) we obtain 
>   $$\left[ \matrix{\beta_1 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_m } \right] = \left[ T(x) \right]_B = \left[ \matrix{ \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{1j} \alpha_j \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{mj} \alpha_j } \right] = \left[ \matrix{ \gamma_{11} & \ldots & \gamma_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \gamma_{m1} & \ldots & \gamma_{mn} } \right] \left[ \matrix{\alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n } \right]. $$
>   That is, [Refer to (1a), (2a), and (5a) above.]
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_B = \left[ T \right]_{EB} \left[ x \right]_E, \tag{A} $$ 
>   where 
>   $$\left[ T \right]_{EB} \colon= \left[ \matrix{ \gamma_{11} & \ldots & \gamma_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \gamma_{m1} & \ldots & \gamma_{mn} } \right] \tag{*} $$
>   is said to be the *matrix* of the linear mapping $T \colon X \to Y$ relative to the ordered basis $E$ of $X$ and the ordreed basis $B$ of $Y$.

Is my analysis correct so far? If so, then is my presentation in conformity with the usual convention in the literature?

I have also got the following question

> Now let $E^\prime = \left( e_1^\prime, \ldots, e_n^\prime \right)$ be another ordered basis for the vector space $X$, and let $B^\prime = \left( b_1^\prime, \ldots, b_m^\prime \right)$ be another ordered basis for $Y$.
>
> Let $\left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime}$ denote the matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $E^\prime$ of $X$ and the ordered basis $B^\prime$ of $Y$.
>
> Then what is the relation, if any, between $\left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime}$  and $\left[ T \right]_{EB}$?

My effort:

> As $e_1^\prime, \ldots, e_n^\prime \in X$ and as $E = \left( e_1, \ldots, e_n \right)$ is an ordered basis for $X$, so we can find unique $n$-tuples
>   $$ \left( \lambda_{11}, \ldots, \lambda_{n1} \right), \ldots, \left( \lambda_{1n}, \ldots, \lambda_{nn} \right)$$ 
>   of scalars such that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> e_1^\prime &= \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{k1} e_k, \\
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> e_n^\prime &= \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{kn} e_k.
> \end{align} \tag{6} 
> $$
>   Thus the coordinate vectors of $e_1^\prime, \ldots, e_n^\prime$ relative to the basis $E$ of $X$ are given by 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left[ e_1^\prime \right]_{E} &= \left[ \matrix{ \lambda_{11} \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_{n1} } \right], \\
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> \left[ e_n^\prime \right]_{E} &= \left[ \matrix{ \lambda_{1n} \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_{nn} } \right]. 
> \end{align} \tag{6a}
> $$
>   Now as $x \in X$ and as $\left( e_1^\prime, \ldots, e_n^\prime \right)$ is an ordered basis for $X$, so there exists a unique ordered $n$-tuple $\left( \alpha_1^\prime, \ldots, \alpha_n^\prime \right)$ of scalars such that 
>   $$ x = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j^\prime e_j^\prime. \tag{7}$$ 
>   so that the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the ordered basis $E^\prime$ of $X$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ x \right]_{E^\prime} = \left[ \matrix{ \alpha_1^\prime \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n^\prime } \right]. \tag{7a} $$
>   Now, using (6) in (7), we obtain 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> x &= \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j^\prime e_j^\prime \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \alpha_j^\prime \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{kj} e_k \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_j^\prime \lambda_{kj} e_k \right) \\
> &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n  \lambda_{kj} \alpha_j^\prime e_k \right) \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{kj} \alpha_j^\prime e_k \right) \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{kj} \alpha_j^\prime \right) e_k.  
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   That is, 
>   $$ x = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{kj} \alpha_j^\prime \right) e_k,  \tag{8} $$
>   so that the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the ordered basis $E$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ x \right]_E = \left[ \matrix{ \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{1j} \alpha_j^\prime \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{nj} \alpha_j^\prime } \right]. \tag{8a} $$
>   Then from (1a) and (8a), we obtain 
>   $$ \left[ \matrix{\alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n } \right] = \left[x \right]_E = \left[ \matrix{ \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{1j} \alpha_j^\prime \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_{nj} \alpha_j^\prime } \right] = \left[ \matrix{ \lambda_{11} & \ldots & \lambda_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \lambda_{n1} & \ldots & \lambda_{nn}  } \right] \left[ \matrix{\alpha_1^\prime \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n^\prime } \right]. $$
>   That is, 
>   $$ \left[ x \right]_E = M_{E^\prime E} \left[ x \right]_{E^\prime}, \tag{B}$$
>   where 
>   $$ M_{E^\prime E} \colon= \left[ \matrix{ \lambda_{11} & \ldots & \lambda_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \lambda_{n1} & \ldots & \lambda_{nn}  } \right] \tag{**}$$ 
>   is the *change-of-basis matrix* from the ordered basis $E^\prime$ to the ordered basis $E$ of $X$.
>
> Now as $b_1, \ldots, b_m \in Y$ and as $B^\prime = \left( b_1^\prime, \ldots, b_m^\prime \right)$ is an ordered basis for $Y$, so there exist unique $m$-tuples 
>   $$\left( \mu_{11}, \ldots, \mu_{m1} \right), \ldots, \left( \mu_{1m}, \ldots, \mu_{mm} \right) $$
>   of scalars such that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> b_1 &= \sum_{r=1}^m \mu_{r1} b_r^\prime, \\
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> b_m &= \sum_{r=1}^m \mu_{rm} b_r^\prime.
> \end{align} \tag{9}
> $$
>   Thus the coordinate vectors of $b_1, \ldots, b_m$ relative to the ordered basis $B^\prime$ of $Y$ are given by 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left[ b_1 \right]_{B^\prime} &= \left[ \matrix{ \mu_{11} \\ \vdots \\ \mu_{m1} } \right], \\ 
> \cdots &= \cdots, \\
> \left[ b_m \right]_{B^\prime} &= \left[ \matrix{ \mu_{1m} \\ \vdots \\ \mu_{m m} } \right].
> \end{align} \tag{9a} 
> $$
>   Now as $T(x) \in Y$ and as $B^\prime$ is an ordered basis for $Y$, so there exists a unique ordered $m$-tuple $\left( \beta_1^\prime, \ldots, \beta_m^\prime \right)$ of scalars such that 
>   $$ T(x) = \sum_{r=1}^m \beta_r^\prime b_r^\prime. \tag{10} $$
>   So the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to the ordered basis $B^\prime$ of $Y$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_{B^\prime} = \left[ \matrix{\beta_1^\prime \\ \vdots \\ \beta_m^\prime } \right]. \tag{10a} $$ 
>   Now from (2) and (9), we see that 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> T(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i b_i \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \beta_i \sum_{r=1}^m \mu_{ri} b_r^\prime \right) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{r=1}^m \beta_i \mu_{ri} b_r^\prime \right) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{r=1}^m \mu_{ri} \beta_i  b_r^\prime \right) \\
> &= \sum_{r=1}^m \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_{ri} \beta_i  b_r^\prime \right) \\
> &= \sum_{r=1}^m \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_{ri} \beta_i \right) b_r^\prime. 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   That is, 
>   $$ T(x) = \sum_{r=1}^m \left( \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_{ri} \beta_i \right) b_r^\prime. \tag{11} $$
>   Thus the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to the ordered basis $B^\prime$ of $Y$ is given by 
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_{B^\prime} = \left[ \matrix{ \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_{1i} \beta_i \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_{mi} \beta_i  } \right] = \left[ \matrix{\mu_{11} & \ldots & \mu_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \mu_{m1} & \ldots & \mu_{mm} } \right] \left[ \matrix{ \beta_1 \\ \vdots \\ \beta_m } \right] . \tag{11a} $$ 
>   From (10a) and (11a) we get 
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_{B^\prime} = M_{BB^\prime} \left[ T(x) \right]_{B}, \tag{C} $$ 
>   where 
>   $$ M_{BB^\prime} \colon= \left[ \matrix{\mu_{11} & \ldots & \mu_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \mu_{m1} & \ldots & \mu_{mm} } \right] \tag{***} $$ 
>   is the *change-of-basis matrix* from the ordered basis $B$ of $Y$ to the ordered basis $B^\prime$.
>
> Now just as in (A) above, we can also write 
>   $$ \left[ T(x) \right]_{B^\prime} = \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} \left[ x \right]_{E^\prime}, \tag{D} $$ 
>   where $ \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} $ denotes the matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $E^\prime$ of $X$ and the ordered basis $B^\prime$ of $Y$.
>
> Now using (B) and (C) in (D), we get 
>   $$ M_{BB^\prime} \left[ T(x) \right]_{B}  = \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} M_{E^\prime E}^{-1} \left[ x \right]_E, $$
>   provided $M_{E^\prime E}^{-1}$  exists.

Now intuitively I know that this inverse exists as all the ordered bases are linearly independent. Is it really so? If so, then how to prove this fact rigorously?

> Now using (A) in the last equation, we obtain 
>   $$ M_{BB^\prime} \left[ T \right]_{EB} \left[ x \right]_E = \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} M_{E^\prime E}^{-1} \left[ x \right]_E,$$ 
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \left[ T \right]_{EB} \left[ x \right]_E = M_{BB^\prime}^{-1} \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} M_{E^\prime E}^{-1} \left[ x \right]_E, $$
>   provided of course that $M_{BB^\prime}^{-1}$ exists, which it does I think.
>
> Now from the last equation we obtain 
>   $$ \left(  \left[ T \right]_{EB} - M_{BB^\prime}^{-1} \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} M_{E^\prime E}^{-1} \right) \left[ x \right]_E = \mathbf{0}_{K^m} $$ 
>   for all points $x \in X$, where $\mathbf{0}_{K^m}$ denotes the zero vector in $K^m$.
>
> In the last equation, we can successively put $e_1$, $\ldots$, $e_n$ in place of $x$, and thus obtain 
>   $$  \left[ T \right]_{EB} = M_{BB^\prime}^{-1} \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime} M_{E^\prime E}^{-1}, $$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \left[ T \right]_{E^\prime B^\prime}   = M_{BB^\prime} \left[ T \right]_{EB} M_{E^\prime E}.  \tag{E} $$

Is (E) the required relation?

Is my calculation correct so far? If so, have I been able to conform to the standard notation? Have I managed to remain consistent enough in the use of symbols? If so, then how to proceed from here?

If not, then where have I erred? where have I failed to maintain consistency?

Comment: Your approach is longer than necessary, but quite okay. The result (E) is correct. The notation is not bad. I don't think you have to change it.

Comment: @janmarqz what is it in my post that you've editted, I wonder?

Comment: @Fakemistake can you please suggest some book where this topic has been covered?

Comment: I'm not very good in english literature about linear algebra, because it's not my native language and i'm not in possession in some book. So i guess, i cannot really help you. What you also can do is to search after lecture notes.

Comment: You can search in a library for authors like Serge Lang, Werner Greub or Sheldon Axler with Linear Algebra. You can also try to search some books on linear algebra on publisher sites like springer ...

Comment: @Fakemistake I have just reviewed my post and corrected some errors. Can you please have a look at it again and see if it is any better this time around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post is quite ok until you arrived at equation (D). From there I prefer another way and before I show you this way, I will repeat the important equations:

> \begin{align}
> [T(x)]_B&=[T]_{EB}\cdot [x]_E\tag{A}\\
> [x]_E&=M_{E'E}\cdot [x]_{E'}\tag{B}\\
> [T(x)]_{B'}&=M_{BB'}\cdot [T(x)]_B\tag{C}\\
> [T(x)]_{B'}&=[T]_{E'B'}\cdot [x]_{E'}\tag{D}
> \end{align}

You asked what the relation between $[T]_{EB}$ and $[T]_{E'B'}$ is. Here is my suggestion:

> Start with equation $(\mathrm{C})$ and insert equation $(\mathrm{A})$ first and equation $(\mathrm{B})$ second to get
>   \begin{align}
> [T(x)]_{B'}&=M_{BB'}\cdot [T(x)]_B\\
> &\!\stackrel{(\mathrm{A})}{=}M_{BB'}\cdot [T]_{EB}\cdot [x]_E\\
> &\!\overset{(\mathrm{B})}{=}M_{BB'}\cdot [T]_{EB}\cdot M_{E'E}\cdot [x]_{E'}
> \end{align}
>   The result is 
>   $$[T(x)]_{B'}=M_{BB'}\cdot [T]_{EB}\cdot M_{E'E}\cdot [x]_{E'}$$
>   Now compare this equation with equation $(\mathrm{D})$ and you will get the final result
>   $$[T]_{E'B'}=M_{BB'}\cdot [T]_{EB}\cdot M_{E'E}$$
>   which is the same as equation $(\mathrm{E})$ in your calculation. But in my calculation you don't have to prove that $M_{E'E}^{-1}$ exists. I say carefully that this is the better way. What is your opinion?

Comment: yes, your approach is much better, but it depends on the following implication: If $A$ and $B$ are $m \times n$ matrices over a field and if $Ax = Bx$ for every $n \times 1$ matrix $x$ over $F$, then $A = B$. Am I right? If so, then this perhaps too needs to be rigorously proved too.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Yes this is correct! If $Ax=Bx$ then $(A-B)x=0$. Since this must be true for each $x\in X$ we must have $A-B=0$ and consequently $A=B$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Don't forget that the transformation matrix is unique when you fix a basis in $X$ and $Y$. We have found one and so we know that this is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two bases $E$ and $E'$. Make a transformation from the $E$ to $E'$ and back to $E$. This change of basis is represented by the identity matrix $I$. Is $M_{E,E'}$ the change of basis matrix from $E$ to $E'$ and $T_{E',E}$ the change of basis matrix from $E'$ to $E$, then we have $I=T_{E',E}M_{E,E'}$, so $M$ and $T$ are invertible and $T=M^{-1}$

Comment: thanks. Can you please also take an in-depth look at my post and answer the other questions?

Comment: Which other questions? Existence of an invertible matrix caused by the linear independence of an ordered basis?

Comment: yes, of course. And, if what I've done is correct and rigorous enough.

Comment: which book has this topic been covered in detail?